# jquery save width before resize

Tags: jquery

How can I add a clause into this code that saves the previous width into a variable before it resizes each time?

```
 $(window).on('load resize', function() {           
      var w = $(window).width();
      var h = $(window).height();

      $('#right1').css('top' , w > 1250 ? -120 : -73 );  

    });
```

Comment: With a global var prevHeight and prevWidth and prevWidth = $(window).width(); ?

Comment: With `data` on the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var oldW = $(window).width();
var oldH = $(window).height();

$(window).on('load resize', function () {
  var w = $(window).width();
  var h = $(window).height();

  $('#right1').css('top', w > 1250 ? -120 : -73);

  //Finish what you want with oldH and oldW.... 
  oldH = h;
  oldW = w;
});
```

Comment: Can I do this? ratio = OldW - w;  $('#right1').css('top', w > 1250 ? w- ratio : -73);

Comment: @MG1, it's a variable, you can do what ever you like with it.